# Prevent browser from downloading files into specific folder

Tags: permissions, directory

Now, this might be an oddly specific question. But is it possible to make it impossible for browsers to download files into a specific folder?

The issue appears because I don't want the browser to download things into a default folder, that's why my setting is to choose the folder every time. However, I want to prevent myself from downloading stuff into a specific folder by mistake

Comment: Well the issue appears because I don't want the browser to download things into a default folder, that's why my setting is to choose the folder every time. However, I want to prevent myself from downloading stuff into a specific folder by mistake

Comment: It was a reply to someone's comment which now seems to be gone

Comment: Yes, it was my comment. Removed when you answered. Comments are not intended for conversation. Comments are temporary; transient; intended to help you ask a better question.